# Non attainable claim - Incomplete market

Tags: derivatives, brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure, hedging, continuous-time

I am wondering whether there is a standard procedure to find a non attainable (i.e. non replicable) asset in an incomplete market.
As an example, let us have the following market ($B = (B^1, B^2, B^3)$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-SBM):
$$dX_t^0 = 0 \\
dX_t^1 = dt + dB_t^1 + dB_t^2 - dB_t^3 \\
dX_t^2 = 5dt - dB_t^1 + dB_t^2 + dB_t^3$$
This is clearly incomplete (number of risky assets is less than dimension of the underlying brownian motion), which means a non attainable claim exists. 
How do I find such a claim? What should I look for?